# jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal unable to file glTranslatef

Tags: jogl

Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.3

Attempting to get the tutorial "spaceinvaders103" working using jogl 2.0, see:

http://www.cokeandcode.com/node/9

Create a project folder which includes:

jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal

src/org/newdawn/spaceinvaders

bin/...

Try to compile from the project folder using:

```
>javac
-Xlint
-d bin 
-sourcepath src
-classpath
.
:jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal/lib/jogl.all.jar
:jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal/lib/nativewindow.all.jar
:jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal/lib/gluegen-rt.jar
:jogl-2.0-pre-20100528-macosx-universal/lib/newt.all.jar
src/org/newdawn/spaceinvaders/Game.java
```

I find many 'gl' methods are missing:

```
src/org/newdawn/spaceinvaders/jogl/JoglSprite.java:105: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method glTranslatef(float,float,float)
location: interface javax.media.opengl.GL
  gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

and
`glColor3f`, 
`glTexCoord2f`, 
`glBegin`, ....

but others it can find.

I've found these methods in source I pulled down with git:
(lost track where I got it and there isn't anything in the src to say where it came from - but it was a '231' version)

is `glTranslatef` obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

His tutorial uses a completely obsolete version of JOGL, neither JOGL 1.1 nor JOGL 2.0. JOGL 2.0 has introduced the concept of profile and glTranslatef is no more in the GL class but rather in the GL2 class.